# Aurora error handling with LOAD DATA FROM S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-aurora

I'm loading a chunk of data to Aurora MySQL, and have some data problems.

My file has about 15m rows and I find some error at row ~5m. I can find the 'bad row' and investigate / remove / recreate the raw data but I wonder if there's some kind of error log, tolerance, or other threshold that can

- allow the process to continue / succeed and simply report number of errors
- put the error rows into a system table for review
- allow the process to continue until a threshold is exceeded (e.g. 100 errors)

For example, when using Redshift we leverage the [`MAXERROR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) option.

This type of functionality is really important when building automated processes for larger datasets. I can't find anything in the Aurora documentation; if this doesn't exist are there other patterns to achieve the same result?